# File "C:\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode raise json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm trying to open and load .json file but the error appears. I'm working on windows 10.

in main the fragment of code is:

```
nazwapliku = nick + ".json" 
losowania = czytaj_json(nazwapliku)
```

and the function code is:

```
def czytaj_json(nazwapliku):
dane = []
if os.path.isfile(nazwapliku):
    with open(nazwapliku, "r") as plik:
        dane = json.load(plik)
return dane
```

The json file is empty at the first time it start.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "extra_lotek_f.py", line 48, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "extra_lotek_f.py", line 31, in main
    losowania = czytaj_json(nazwapliku)
  File "C:\Users\Comarch\Desktop\prog python\extra_lotek_mod_1.py", line 27, in czytaj_json
    dane = json.load(plik)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", line 296, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve] and the error message in your question as formatted text. Screenshots of text are not appropriate.

Comment: The error seems pretty clear? Your file doesn't contain valid JSON.

Comment: Can you provide json file too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json file cannot be empty, you must specify [] inside your file first.